# Что это значит в SQL запросе?

Tags: mysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `forecast` AS `forecast`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        `forecast_event` AS `events->forecast_event` --- Что это?
        INNER JOIN `event` AS `events` ON `events`.`id` = `events->forecast_event`.`eventId`
    ) ON `forecast`.`id` = `events->forecast_event`.`forecastId`
```

Суть его в том, что он получает записи меду отношением одной сущности к многим в другой сущности, через junction таблицу.

И тут есть несколько вопросов:

1)
Такого я не видел:

`forecast_event AS events->forecast_event`

В подзапросе можно не писать `SELECT * FROM`?

2)
В join можно указать таблицу, например, JOIN table1, а что, можно сделать join на основании выборки из определенных данных?

Comment: это просто алиас таблицы

Comment: А SELECT FROM можно опустить в этом случае? Это вообще подзапрос?

Comment: скобки в join - особенность синтаксиса mysql, обратитесь к документации

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html